# somethingGoesWrong (PYTHON) - brainChallenge

Tags: python, list

So, I've got this script.

```
lista = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'X',0,0]

jump = 5
lista2 = list()
for i in range(10):
    lista2.append(0)

for lettera in lista:
    # check if list[i] + jump is more then list len, if FALSE put that 'X' in place,
    # if TRUE go throught list and go back to lista[0] and put that 'X' in rightplace.

    # example: len_list = 10 | start_position = list[7] | jump = 5 | final_position = list[2]
    # rember that count start on list[0]

    control = lista.index(lettera) + jump

    if control < len(lista):
        lista2[lista.index(lettera)] = lettera
    else:
        differenza = control - len(lista)
        lista2[differenza] = lettera


print(lista2)
```

so, that's it. Everything work right?
Now, Try with this:

```
msg = 'GAr cnff78eq vfGr8L4qetPEsslog32gdsoRK8XSP6x2RHh'

msgSplit = []

msgShuffle = list() #where the final product goes
for i in range(len(msg)): #start with a the same numbers of element(msg)
    msgShuffle.append('*')

def split_msg(msg):
    #split msg letter into list
    for i in msg:
        msgSplit.append(i)

    return msgSplit

def shuffle_msg(lista,lista2):
    for i in lista:
        control = lista.index(i) + 13 #13 here is the 'jump'

        if control < len(lista):
            lista2[lista.index(i)] = i
        else:
            differenza = control - len(lista)
            lista2[differenza] = i

################# T  E  S  T  #################
split_msg(msg)
print(msgSplit)
print('----------------')
shuffle_msg(msgSplit, msgShuffle)
print(msgShuffle)
```

if u run that program this is the output:

```
['G', 'u', 'r', ' ', 'c', 'n', 'f', 'f', 'j', 'b', 'e', 'q', ' ', 'v', 'f', ' ', '5', 'G', 'r', '8', 'L', '4', 'q', 'e', 't', 'P', 'E', 's', 'P', 'k', '8', 'h', 't', 'q', 'j', 'h', 'R', 'K', '8', 'X', 'S', 'P', '6', 'x', '2', 'R', 'H', 'h']
----------------
['G', 'R', 'K', ' ', 'X', 'S', 'f', '6', 'x', '2', 'e', 'H', '', 'v', '', '', '5', '', '', '8', 'L', '4', '', '', 't', 'P', 'E', 's', '', 'k', '', 'h', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

the first is the string split into list(msgSplit) 
the second is msgSplit after i've passed it into a function (shuffle_msg) that u can see in script.

80% of element now is ''.
so what's the problem???
the function just have to move the element in list.

thanks!

that's the idea:

```
@ = list[4]

so now we want to move @ forward for 3 position:
[o,o,o,o,@,o] start @=list[4]
[o,o,o,o,o,@] +1 @=list[5]
[@,o,o,o,o,o] +2 the list is finish so we continue from @=list[0]
[o,@,o,o,o,o] +3 finish on @=list[1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use links to code. Add the code in your post (I have done this for you this time).

Comment: Note, you can split a string into a list with `msgSplit = list(msg)` so there's no need for the `split_msg` function.

Comment: Another note, you can create a list of repeated chars with `msgShuffle = ['*'] * len(msg)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks!

Comment: @you have find why  msgShuffle() doesn't work properly?

Comment: No, but then I don't really get what you are doing here. Can you add the desired output?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i put some graphical example down to the post i hope is clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to *right rotate* the array. You can modify your code slightly:

```
def shuffle_msg(lista, lista2):
    # Using indexes, not values
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        # control is the target index in the other list
        control = i + 13 #13 here is the 'jump'

        # If not out of bounds, insert it
        if control < len(lista):
            lista2[control] = lista[i]
        # Else, wrap around
        else:
            differenza = control - len(lista)
            lista2[differenza] = lista[i]
```

You could simplify this a bit using modulo:

```
def shuffle_msg2(lista, lista2):
    # Using enumerate instead of range
    for i, val in enumerate(lista):
        lista2[(i + 13) % len(lista)] = val
```

You could simplify even more using list slicing:

```
msgShuffle = msg[-13:] + msg[:-13]
```

There are other ways as well.